# Salto de línea HTML textarea a js

Tags: textarea

Buenas tardes para todos, quisiera su ayuda. (*Estoy iniciando hasta ahora en este mundo de la programación).*

Estoy realizando un formulario en HTML y lo capturo la info  en js para pasarlo a pdf con jspdf  pero lo  capturado en un textarea  no me sale el salto de línea si pasa el numero de "cols" y cambia de linea en html, solo se evidencia el salto  si el usuario no le da enter.

HTML
`

```
          <label for="comment">
            <span>Comentario/descripcion actividades</span>
          </label>
                        
          <div>
            <label for="comment">            
              <p></p>
              <textarea id="comment"   name="comm" rows="12"  cols="92"  wrap="hard" placeholder="comentario/descripcion:"
               style="resize:none ;"></textarea>
              </label>
          </div>`
```

JS

`let comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;

pdf.text(comment, 25, 432);`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo quieres en Javascript? No te sirve css? Si te sirve css le pudes poner overflow:hidden;
word-wrap: break-word. A ver si te funciona.

Comment: gracias @jbort , voy a buscar como ponerle css a ese textarea  y el layout overflow  que mencionas, por ahora solo el form lo he manejado en html y capturo la info  con js,  no he usado css esta solito html...